# How to install rain screen over split face block to stop leaks?

Tags: water, waterproofing

I own a condo in Chicago and am facing water issues due to the single wythe use of split face block(SFB). My window sills were always wet so I pulled off the drywall and saw that the insulation and wood studs were right up against the SFB and were soaking wet.

This seems to be a pretty common issue in Chicago. Is the rain screen as described [here](http://inspection2020.com/SFB.pdf) my only option? Is there anything else I can consider?